# Could not add menu item to Egit history View menu

Tags: egit

In Egit, ..... when right click the project, then click "Show in History", the history View shows the list of all commits, select one commit, right click , the pop up menu shows (Checkout, Create Branch, Create Tag, .....Revision Comment). What I need to do is to add a new item in this pop up menu called "Add To Factory", then when click it , go to "AddToFactoryHandler" to do the implementation.

From the source code in Egit, this menu id is "org.eclipse.egit.ui.historyPageContributions",

```
(1)
    <extension  point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
          <command
                id="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory"
                defaultHandler="xxxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactoryHandler"
                description="description"
                name="AddToFactory">
          </command>
    </extension>

    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
        <handler  
             commandId="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory">
             <class
                   class="xxxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactoryHandler">
             </class>
               <activeWhen>
                <and>
                   <count
                         value="1">
                   </count>
                   <iterate>
                      <adapt
                            type="org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ReflogEntry">
                      </adapt>
                   </iterate>
                </and>
             </activeWhen>
        </handler>
    </extension>

    <extension
             point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
          <menuContribution
                locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.egit.ui.historyPageContributions">

             <command
                   commandId="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory"
                   label="AddToFactory"
                   style="push">
             </command>
      </extension> 

(2) <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.egit.ui.historyPageContributions">
         <command commandId="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory" style="push">
            <visibleWhen checkEnabled="true"/>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>


   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="xxxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactoryHandler"
            commandId="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory">
         <enabledWhen>
            <and>
               <with variable="activePartId">
                  <equals value="org.eclipse.egit.ui.historyPageContributions"/>
               </with>
               <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
                  <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                     <adapt type="org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ReflogEntry"/>
                  </iterate>
               </with>
            </and>
         </enabledWhen>
      </handler>
   </extension>
```

Either way, when I select the commit in the history view and right clcik , "AddToFActory" never show up in the pop up menu.  Any idea how to add item to such pop up menu? Thanks a lot for the help?

Comment: If you remove the `visiblewhen` (or change it so that it's always true), does it work then?

Comment: THanks for reply, no, I have tried removing "visiblewhen, enabledWhen", and never make it work. Just wondering Egit rumtime override the settings I put in "plugin.xml"?